# Deployment approach to bring down time for Java

Tags: deployment, time

We have our J2EE based application basically It is small e-commerce apps that run across global (multiple time zones). When ever we have to deploy the patch it take around 3 hrs time (DB backup,DB changes,Java changes,QA smoke testing). I knew its too high. I want to bring down this deployment time to less than 30 mins. 
Now I would brief about application infra: We got two Jboss server and single DB, load balancer is configured for both jboss server. It is not cluster env.
Currently what we do :
We bring down both jboss and DB
Take DB backup
Make the DB changes, run some script 
Make the java changes, run patches 
Above steps will take around 2 hrs for us
Than QA will do testing for one hr.  than bring up the server.

Can you suggest some better approach to achieve this?  My main question, when we have multiple jboss and single DB. How to make deployment smooth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach I've heard that Netflix uses, but have not had a chance to use myself:

1. Make all of your DB schema changes both forward and backward compatible with the current version of software running, and the one you are about to deploy.  Make the new software version continue to write any data the old version needs. Hopefully this is a minimal set.
2. Backup your running DB (most DBs don't require downtime for backups), and deploy your database schema updates at least a week prior to your software deploy.
3. Once your db changes have burnt in and seem to be bug free with the current running version, reconfigure your load balancer to point to only one instance of your JBoss servers.  Deploy your updated software to the other instance and have QA smoke test it offline while the other server continues to server production request.
4. When QA is happy with the results, point the LB to just the offline JBoss server (with the new software).  When that comes online, update the software on the newly offline JBoss server, and have QA smoke test if desired.  If successful, point the LB to both JBoss instances.
5. If QA finds major bugs, and a quick bug fix and "roll-forward" is not possible, roll back to the previous version of the deployed software.  Since your schema and new code is backward compatible, you won't have lost data.
6. On your next deploy, remove any garbage from your schema (like columns unused by the current deploy) in a way that makes it still backward and forward compatible.

Although more complex than your current approach, this approach should reduce your deployment downtime with minimal risk.

Comment: Thanks a lot... 
Got the point and make sense to me. I just got two more questions
1. When we take the backup of running DB, we may loose some data that’s getting inserted while backup is going on?
2. When we turn off Jboss from LB, user who log-in in via this Jboss IP. They may loose the session. How to handle?

Comment: #1 -  You would suffer data loss if you had to restore from backup. Make sure everything is well tested prior to production deploy, using a production-like environment, to reduce the risk of needing backups. You'll have to assess the chances and cost of that happening versus the occasional long outages your customers are experiencing.  #2 - Not sure what you are using for a servlet container in JBoss, but if it's Tomcat, you can enable state replication across your two nodes.  This will copy session info to all nodes so a user is not logged out when one node goes down.